# Protobuf structure with bytes field

Tags: protocol-buffers

There is a protobuf structures

```
message A {
  bytes B = 1;
}

message B {
   int32 c = 1;
   int64 d = 2;
   string x = 3;
}
```

If we put the bytes of the same encoded proto-buffer in the A.B field
and decode or encode

```
pseudocode: 
newA = &A{}
newB = &B{x:"123",c:1,d:3}
bytes_of_B = marshall(type(B), newB) 
newA.B = bytes_of_B
bytes_of_A = marshall(type(A), newA)

pseudocode: 
newA = unmarshall(bytes_of_A, type(A))
newB = unmarshall(newA.B, type(B))
```

how true is this and what may be the consequences of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the wire/payload level, this scenario is 100% identical to

```proto
message A {
  B B = 1;
}
```

So: no consequences as such, but telling A to expect a B may be more convenient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to have a structure and parse another one from bytes (depending on the parser where it gets to, something like generics)

Comment: @vl4deee11 you might also want to look at `oneof`, or [`.google.protobuf.Any`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/any.proto) (which works in a very different way)